# Does Solr DocValues improve Grouping performance?

Tags: solr, lucene, fieldcollapsing

Does use of DocValues provide any performance improvement for Grouping ? 
I' looked into the blog which mentions improving Grouping performance 
through DocValues.

https://lucidworks.com/blog/fun-with-docvalues-in-solr-4-2/

Right now, Group by queries (which I can't sadly avoid) has become a huge 
bottleneck. It has an overhead of 60-70% compared to the same query san 
group by. Unfortunately, I'm not able to be CollapsingQParserPlugin as it 
doesn't have a support similar to "group.facet" feature.

My understanding on DocValues is that it's intended for faceting and 
sorting. Just wondering if anyone have tried DocValues for Grouping and saw 
any improvements?

Comment: yes, i write some code that act similar to grouping (block join stuff) and I used docvalues, it helps.

Comment: @Mysterion .. thanks, I'm giving it a shot, hopefully will see some improvement.

Comment: @Shamik did you see any improvement?

Comment: @BestPractices .. Unfortunately no, docvalues didn't make any difference in grouping performance. I'm looking forward to this --> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4763 . I don't see any traction on CollapsingQParserPlugin group.facet support yet.

Comment: @Shamik did you have any luck improving group.facet performance?

Comment: My understanding of the CollapseQParserPlugin is that it facets based on the grouped results. Is that your intent? From the ticket that created the feature, it says, "The result count and facet counts automatically line up with the collapsed doclist/docset."

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-9328 Sorting by DocValues while grouping is slower than old good FieldCache